# Does System.Collections.Immutable.IImmutableList<T>.Add from Microsoft's Preview of Immutable Collections have a position requirement?

Tags: c#, collections, functional-programming, immutability, immutable-collections

I am implementing an immutable collection, which provides O(1) stack operations and O(log n) list operations. As a result, adding elements to the front is faster than adding elements to the back. Can a valid implementation of `System.Collections.Immutable.IImmutableList<T>.Add()`(https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx)  add an element to the front of the collection instead of the back?

Here is how the interface is defined:

```
     [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1710:IdentifiersShouldHaveCorrectSuffix", Justification = "Ignored")]
     public interface IImmutableList<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
     {
         IEqualityComparer<T> ValueComparer { get; }

         // Summary:
         //     Adds the specified value to this list.
         //
         // Parameters:
         //   value:
         //     The value to add.
         //
         // Returns:
         //     A new list with the element added, or this list if the element is already
         //     in this list.
         IImmutableList<T> Add(T value);
         //
         // Summary:
         //     Adds the specified values to this list.
         //
         // Parameters:
         //   items:
         //     The values to add.
         //
         // Returns:
         //     A new list with the elements added, or this list if the elements are already
         //     in this list.
         IImmutableList<T> AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items);
         IImmutableList<T> Clear();
         bool Contains(T value);
         int IndexOf(T value);
         IImmutableList<T> Insert(int index, T element);

         IImmutableList<T> InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> items);
         IImmutableList<T> Remove(T value);

         IImmutableList<T> RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match);
         IImmutableList<T> RemoveAt(int index);
         IImmutableList<T> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> items);

         IImmutableList<T> RemoveRange(int index, int count);

         IImmutableList<T> Replace(T oldValue, T newValue);

         IImmutableList<T> SetItem(int index, T value);

         IImmutableList<T> WithComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer);
}
```

Comment: How can an `IImmutableList<T>` even have an `Add` method? Isn't it supposed to be immutable?

Comment: Agreed. If it did have an Add method, it would need to return a new copy of the list rather that modifying the original one to remain immutable. If it works like `List<T>` does, you would use `Insert` to add a member at a certain position.

Comment: @neontapir Right, and that would not be an O(1) operation. (Rather O(N))

Comment: I'm not familiar with this interface; can you show us its definition?

Comment: Is `IImmutableList<T>` your own interface? If so, it can do whatever you want. I don't think consumers of an immutable list would be surprised if insertion happened at the front of the list though.

Comment: @Magnus That's not true. It is perfectly common for immutable data structures to have methods to have methods that add to the collection (i.e. return a new immutable collection with the given item added to it) that work in O(1) or O(log n) time depending on the data structure.

Comment: @sepp2k If it returns a new immutable collection, all the items needs to be copied to the new list or?

Comment: @Magnus - You don't need to copy the whole collection. The new head of the list has a reference to the old head as the tail of the new list.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention that I was referencing the Immutable Collections preview for the next version of the .Net BCL

Comment: An immutable collections add method returns a copy, which share most of its memory with original but has the given element added.

Comment: @Lee IImmutableList<T> is not my own interface. It is provided in the immutable collections preview for the next version of the .Net BCL (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable).

Comment: @EricLippert - I put in the definition.

Comment: So you're asking the general public if a brand-new, no-official-documentation interface that no one except the BCL team has ever implemented comes with a particular restriction? It's not clear to me by what process you'd imagine that anyone here would know. Address your question to the BCL team.

Comment: That said: I would find it *extremely surprising* if Add inserted on the beginning of a list.

Comment: @EricLippert How would I go about addressing the BCL team directly?

Comment: @SaagarAhluwalia: You could use the "contact the authors" link on the nuget project. Or you could leave a comment on the blog post that you linked to. Or you could ask on the MSDN forums, which is at... ah, you already did.